# WPF - Conditional binding in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm very new to WPF, and am just getting started with data binding.  What I'd like to do is generate a list of checkboxes based on a list in my view model.  The XAML I have at the moment is:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,5,10,5" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This works correctly, and generates a checkbox for every item in `TestList`.  What I'd like to do is only generate checkboxes for items where the condition `TestList[i].Type == "Mode"` is true.  I believe that I may need to use a `<DataTrigger>` element, but I don't know the details of how to do this.

[EDIT] Just to clarify, each element of `TestList` has `Name`, `Enabled`, and `Type` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guess that you want to make the checkbox appear if TestList.Type changes, I would suggest make a Converter and Bind it to the CheckBox Visibility.

```
public sealed class CheckBoxVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
            return Visibility.Visible;

        var type = (string)value;
        var condition  = (string)parameter;
        return type.Equals(condition) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And then in the dictionary add the reference to **your** namespace

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Projct.Converters;
```

and in the resources dictionary

```
 <converters:CheckBoxVisibilityConverter x:Key="CheckBoxConverter"/>
```

Finally in the xaml

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox
            Margin="10,5,10,5"
            Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource CheckBoxConverter}, ConverterParameter=Mode}" />    
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I think this is probably the way to go, but I'm getting an error `Unknown property 'ConverterParameter' for type 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension'` when I compile the above code.

Comment: @Tevildo make sure you add the xmlns reference to the namespace were your converter is.

Comment: Yes - if I remove the namespace reference, I get `CheckBoxVisibilityConverter not found`.

Comment: @Tevildo ok, I made a typo in the Visibility section in the code sorry. Now should work.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks.  I tried various combinations of brackets and braces in the Visibility parameter, but didn't manage to find the right one.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. However, the simplest *static* approach would be to just filter it at your *ViewModel*

```
Filtered = new ObservableCollection(TestList.Where(x => x.Type == "Mode"));

...

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Filtered , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

<sub>***Note*** : There are fancier more dynamic ways to achieve this, though this might help you out</sub>

Comment: That will work in the short term, but I need one `ItemControl` for each `Type` value, and the number of different `Type` values is likely to change.  Doing it dynamically would be better.

Comment: Maybe you should look into a `CollectionViewSource` or even a `CompositeCollection`.